# MediaButtonReceiver not working when app is in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat, media-buttons

I employed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html) to add `MediaButtonReceiver` feature to my media player app.

It works well so far the app is in forebackground, but as soon as the app enters background it stops receiving media button actions.

**Part of manifest**

```
<service
            android:name=".playback.PlayerService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Part of media player service**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Timber.d("onCreate: ");
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Timber.d("onStartCommand: ");
        sessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, TAG);
        setControllerCompat(new MediaControllerCompat(getApplicationContext(), sessionCompat));
        sessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS);
        sessionCompat.setCallback(sessionCallback);
        setSessionToken(sessionCompat.getSessionToken());
        sessionCompat.setShuffleMode(playerHelper.getShuffleMode());
        sessionCompat.setRepeatMode(playerHelper.getRepeatMode());
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(sessionCompat, intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Please what did I do wrong and how can I make the service receive button actions when the app is in foreground?

Answer (score 2):

Your service should look like this

```
<service android:name=".playback.PlayerService"
         android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial you might find what's wrong.https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I discovered that I wasn't calling `setActive(true)` on the mediasession.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the problem. I made the very stupid mistake of not calling [MediaSessionCompat#setActive(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setActive(boolean)) when the playback has started.